# Taking screenshots from multiple urls in a file

Tags: python, url, screenshot

I'm trying to take screenshots of pages for which I have URLs in a `.txt` file. When I tried just a single URL such as `"http://testing.com"` it works, but when I assign it to a variable instead of directly using a string it's not working. Here's the code:

```
def capture(self, url, output_file):
    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.wait_load()

    file_list = open("LiveSite.txt")
    for site in file_list.readlines():
        time.sleep(5)
        s.capture(site, site + ".png")
```

Comment: Please, elaborate more this part "when I assign to variable instead of string it's not working."

Answer (score 1):

The `site` variable will contain the newline character for every line in the file. You can try:

```
site = site.strip()
```

before calling `s.capture`:

```
def capture(self, url, output_file):
    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.wait_load()

    File_List = open("LiveSite.txt")
    for site in File_List.readlines():
        time.sleep(5)
        site = site.strip()
        s.capture(site, site + ".png")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and ı did what did you say and ı solved problem.